# Inverse of diagonal-constant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's say $A$ is a diagonal-constant matrix with $1$ on the main diagonal and $2$ on the first superdiagonal and other element are zero .

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1& 2& 0& 0& 0&0& ...&0 \\ 0& 1& 2& 0& 0& 0& ...& 0\\0&0&1&2&...\\...&&&&&&&2\\0&0&0&...&&&&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

It is obvious determinant of $A$ is $1$. By manual calculation I can see that

$$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1& -2& 4& &&&&-2^{m-1} \\0& 1& -2& 4& &&&2^{m-2}\\ &&\\&&&\\\\0&0&0&&&1&-2&4\\0&0&0&&&&1&-2\\0&0&0&...&&&&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Is there a way to prove what the inverse of $A$ would be?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Don't you already have the inverse of $A$, $A^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a coordinate-free (geometric) proof. If so, $A$ can be written as the sum of the identity linear transformation, $I$, and twice a nilpotent transformation $B$ of order $n$ (where $n$ is the size of the matrix).  So,
$$
A = I + 2 B,
$$
where $B^{n} = 0 \, I$ (nilpotence).  So, $A$ can be inverted using a geometric series in $-2B$.  This series is finite because of the nilpotence.

Comment: @leo yes I wrote both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ , but I cannot prove it. I calculated the $A^{-1}$ up to m = 4  manually and guess for higher dimension .

Comment: @avs I am not familiar with nilpotent transformation, I am trying to understand  what you wrote.

Comment: @avs Thanks for your  comment, I understand $A$ can be written as sum of identity matrix plus   $B= \begin{bmatrix} 0 &2& 0& 0& \\ 0& 0& 2&0\\0&0&0&2\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ . I read form Wikipedia that since $B^{n}$ converge to 0 So it is Nilpotent
.  I also learned Given that $C=I+A+A^2+A^3+ \ldots$ , $I-A$ is the inverse of $C$. but I  cannot connect them, since I assumed in $A = I+ 2B$ we have one matrix $A$ and one matrix $B$, which is not a series.

Comment: If the northeast corner is $-2^{m-1}$, then the entry below it is $2^{m-2}$, not $-2^{m-2}$.

Comment: You are right I should either move -2 in parentheses or correct the sign. I will edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B$ is a matrix for which the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty B^k$ converges, then we necessarily have 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty B^k = (I - B)^{-1}
$$
as you can verify by calculation.  Your matrix is an example of this, where we take
$$
B = -\pmatrix{0&2\\&0&2\\&&\ddots  & \ddots\\&&&0&2\\&&&&0}
$$
To see that the sum converges, it suffices to note that $B^k = 0$ whenever $k$ is sufficiently large.

---

Note, however, there is no general formula which makes it easier to take the inverse of a matrix with a constant diagonal.  The formula I presented will work, however, whenever the matrix is triangular (upper triangular or lower triangular) with a constant diagonal, since all strictly triangular matrices are nilpotent.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. According to comments I read earlier and your answer I think I got the picture for this question. A = I + 2B, 2B is strictly upper triangular and nilpotent so the inverse can be written as geometric series and eventually I will get the result. I have studied Calculus  II , III and linear algebra. I have not encountered the nilpotent  proof. Do you know it is taught in what course?

Comment: The idea of nilpotency might be covered in a higher level linear algebra class (especially in the context of Jordan canonical form) or a differential equations class.  The idea of nilpotency is also comes up in abstract algebra, typically in the study of rings.

Comment: @Zereshki, here is the connection.  All you need here is the formal formula 
$$
(1 - x)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...) = 1.
$$
This remains true if $1$ is replaced by $I$, and $x$ by a matrix (like $-2B$ :) that commutes with $I$.  Since $B$ is nilpotent, the above power series will end up being finite.

Comment: @avs Thanks for the details.